# Remove app name and web page address from printing java-script window.print

Tags: javascript, printing

in java-script window.print opens a print preview window with some information added.
I'm trying to only print the information I need without any additional text.

Is it possible to remove the extra text in the print preview window (and the print itself) like application name, address, date and page count? Picture of what I'd like to remove. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove them by disabling **Header and footers** when you run **print** command in your browser (Screenshot is from Chrome by the way).

[image]